# How to append div to row wise in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click on some button I am looking to append the `div` using ID and I would like to display added items each time row wise, maximum of 6 items in a row. The below code is adding to bottom each time, not in horizontal wise. How can i add as  below screenshot ?

[image]

html :

```
<div id="dashboardArea" class="wrapper">
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#saveProjecttoDash").click(function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(300);
    let projectName = document.getElementById("enterprojectName").value;
    let clientName = document.getElementById('clientNametochoose').value;
    var someDiv = '<div class="row"><div class="pull-bottom" style="height:500px;background:#e3e8e7">'+projectName+'<br>'+clientName+'</div></div>';
    $('#dashboardArea').append(someDiv);
  });
});
```

// css for the below class:

```
.pull-bottom {
width: 22%;
margin: 10px 0px 0px 100px;
vertical-align: bottom;
float: none;
    webkit-columns: 2 200px;
     -moz-columns: 2 200px;
          columns: 2 200px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 3em;
     -moz-column-gap: 3em;
          column-gap: 3em;
}
```

Comment: you mean to append each new div like a cell in a table?

Comment: Each appended div to display as screenshot above one after the other maximum of 6 div's. Earlier It was adding  to the bottom of another div, kind of appearing to next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `pull-bottom` CSS class, the `float` property should be `left` in this case.

In the current state, each row will take the full width avalaible.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/fh42xatu/

Comment: It was still not working for me after adding the `float:left`, then I understood I have got a  `display: flex;` property for the row class after removing that it is good now. `.row {  
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}`

Comment: Glad it helped. You should check out Sass if you don't want to bother with vendor prefixes. :)

Comment: Ok will check that, does Sass has good level of users/support ?

Comment: Well, StackOverflow is a fairly decent support I guess. :D

Comment: @soccerway Sass is nonstandard, and has nothing to do with browsers. It's a processed markup that will be transformed by a Sass preprocessor to regular CSS

Answer (score 1):

May be using grid can get you 6 cells.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#save").on("click", function() {
    if ($('#area').children().length == 6)
      return;
    $("<div>", {
      class: "cell",
      append: `Column - ${$('#area').children().length + 1}`,
      appendTo: "#area"
    })
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#area {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.cell {
  background: #fafafa;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="save">SAVE</button>

<div id="area"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex`:

```js
const NewClientProject = (pName, cName) => {
  return $("<div>", {
    class: "cell",
    append: `${pName||"Project Name"}<br>${cName||"Client Name"}`,
    appendTo: "#dashboardArea"
  });
}

jQuery( $ => {

  $("#toDashboard").on("click", function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(300);
    NewClientProject($("#pName").val(), $('#cName').val());
  });
  
});

NewClientProject();
NewClientProject();
```

```css
* {margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;}

#dashboardArea {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

#dashboardArea .cell {
  background: #e3e8e7;
  flex: 0 0 22%;
  margin: 1% 1.5%;
  min-height: 140px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="pName" placeholder="Project Name" type="text">
<input id="cName" placeholder="Client Name" type="text">
<button id="toDashboard">Save to Dashboard</button>

<div id="dashboardArea"></div>
```